# How to prevent focus window when its view is clicked by mouse on OSX?

Tags: macos, cocoa, window, focus

I am writing a Cocoa app and do not want it focus on mouse click it, but I found no way to implement yet. Any one can give me suggestions ?

Answer (score 5):

I've finally found a solution!

Create a subclass of NSView, and reimplement the following methods:

```
-(BOOL) shouldDelayWindowOrderingForEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    return YES;
}

-(void) mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [NSApp preventWindowOrdering];
}
```

and set the contentView property of the created NSWindow, and set the window style mask to NSBorderlessWindowMask , and it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is method(s) you may override in your subclass with returning NO

```
-(BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
-(BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the Table View in Interface Builder. There is a "Focus Ring" Attribute, change it to "None".
I set all these attributes in Scroll View, Clip View, and Table View.

Hope it help.